# What assumptions on $f$ guarantee that $\sup_{|u|\le r} g(u)\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a derivable real function and let
$$ g(u) =\frac{[(f(u^2))^{\prime}]^2}{2}.$$

I am trying to understand under what hypotheses on $f$ we can conclude that $g$ is a continuous function such that for any $r\ge 0$ it is
$$\sup_{|u|\le r} g(u)\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}). $$

Clearly, if $f^{\prime}$ is continuous so it is $g$, but I don't know how to obtain the above assumption on the supremum.

Could someone please help me or give some hints?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $h\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ where $h(r) : = \sup_{|u| \leq r}g(u)$?

Comment: @spaceman yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact $g(u) = 2u^2f'(u)^2$. You can see that \begin{equation}
g \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb R) \Leftrightarrow h \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb R).
\end{equation}
Indeed, if $g\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$, then $h(r) = \sup_{|u|\le r}g(u)\le \left\|g\right\|_{\infty}$ for almost all $r$. Reversly if $h\in L^\infty(\mathbb R)$, $g(u) \le h(|u|+1) \le \left|h\right|_{\infty}$ for almost all $u$.

Using these two the condition that you are looking for is $u\mapsto 2u^2f'(u)^2\in L^\infty\left(\mathbb R\right)$.

Comment: What h denotes? And it is not clear for me the “\iff”.

Comment: $h(r) = \sup_{|u| \le r} g(u)$

Comment: Could you please explain better the relation $h\in L^{\infty}\iff g\in L^{\infty}$?

Comment: I add more details on my answer. Tell me if you find it clear now?

Comment: Could you please explain why $g(u)\le h(|u|+1)$? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is simply because $|u| < |u| + 1$ and use the definition of $h$.

Comment: Sorry, but why you said that $g(u) = 2u^2 f^{\prime}(u)^2$ and not $g(u) = 2u^2 f^{\prime}(u)^2 (u^{\prime})^2$?

Comment: $u' = 1$. Since the variable is $u$